# local developing with changing IP

Tags: linkedin-api, redirect, apache-tomee

I am building a web app using Linkedin api.
linkedin requires a redirect url when requesting permission to use their api (when filling their application form).
since I'm trying to avoid developing on my server instance hosted in aws I want to develop locally (tomee as server framework). The problem I have is developing locally on my machine because my IP is changing and I cant supply Linkedin with a permanent redirect address.

I am pretty new to server side and would like to get some info about workarounds this problem. any possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this problem on a project using Google's APIs by using a reverse proxy, membrane, to send requests to our local boxes. However, you still have to change the ip in the membrane config when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Either http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS or just update your LinkedIn app's settings whenever it changes.